# Long press Android

Tags: android

I have problems with detecting long press in my custom view.

Here's the code related to this issue

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("dbg_msg", "onLongPress");
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```

This code detects every single (short) click as long press.

When I put this code in class inherited from Activity, it works.

So why it isn't working in custom View ?

Comment: Returning true from onTouchEvent fixed this for me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All of this code goes in your custom view class:

```
public static int LONG_PRESS_TIME = 500; // Time in miliseconds 

final Handler _handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable _longPressed = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        Log.i("info","LongPress");
    }   
};

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        _handler.postDelayed(_longPressed, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Should also call removeCallbacks on MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL.

Comment: You should remove ACTION_MOVE because it will cancel the handler.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure but your `GestureDetector`'s constructor is deprecated ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#GestureDetector%28android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener%29)). Could you try other ones which need a context as first parameter?

Sorry I'm new so I can't post comment.

— *Edited* —

It seems you used another listener, this [`View.OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) has other [`onTouch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) method. Could you try again?

— *Edited* —

Here is an example (worked for me):

```
...
mAnotherView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});

...
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // do your tasks here
    }
});
```

Comment: How to do that, I don't get You ?

Comment: You're welcome  :-)  I think you can answer yourself, to help other people reading your question.

Comment: Please accept your answer ([hint](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)). Sorry I talk so much…

Comment: It's ok, I have to wait 48 hours to do that :)

Answer (score 4):

Did you enable long presses on your GestureDetector?  You can enable it either using an appropriate constructor, or by calling [setIsLongpressEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#setIsLongpressEnabled%28boolean%29).  For instance, you can do:

```
gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);
```

in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's better I guess..

```
public class Workflow extends View implements View.OnLongClickListener {

public Workflow(Context context, DisplayFeatures d) {
    super(context);

    setLongClickable(true);
    setOnLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    /* onTouchEvent should return super.onTouchEvent(event);, otherwise long click wouldn't be performed */
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Log.d("VIEW", "LONG CLICK PERFORMED!");
    return false;
}
}
```