# long press radio buttons?

Tags: android, radio-button, touch-event, long-press

Is there built-in support in Android's API for long pressing a radio button, similar to keyboard's [onKeyLongPress()](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html)?

Or must I resort to coding all of it myself, style [onTouchEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11702558)?

Comment: `GestureDetector` will do the job

Comment: @android.h Thanks! This is the first time I encounter [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) and so I am reading this now and I see a sentence that doesn't make sense: *"In the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) method ensure you call onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)."*. A method calling itself??? Is this a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems error. This means, when the `onTouchEvent()` (of any `View`) is called, make sure you call the `onTouchEvent()` of `GestureDetector` object so you can listen double-taps, and/or long-click events.

Comment: @android.h Thanks again! In the meanwhile I discovered [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-gesture-detector-to-translate-a-swipe-into-an-event/1577). It reads exactly what you said.