# How to set OnLongTouch functionality in my onTouchEvent?

Tags: android, onclick, touch-event

I have two invisible areas used as buttons,
When I click a specific area it will increment the speed of bitmap but only if I press that repeatedly.
How can I make it work on LongPressed to increment the speed of the bitmap?

Here is my code :

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                if((event.getX(0)>=1) && 
                          (event.getY(0)>=500) && 
                         ( event.getX(0)<=1+150) && 
                          (event.getY(0)<=500+300))
                          {


                    u--;        

                          }

                if((event.getX(0)>=300) && 
                      (event.getY(0)>=500) && 
                     ( event.getX(0)<=300+150) && 
                      (event.getY(0)<=500+300))
                      {

                u++;

                      }


                       return true; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
    }
 });

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: in every case it says longpress detected

Comment: sorry can you elaborate..? btw as u may have noticed Log.e contains the text "longpress detected"...you may have to put your code there..

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701826/long-press-android?rq=1