# Android do not execute setOnTouchListener if setOnLongClickListener has been executed

Tags: java, android, methods, onclick, onclicklistener

I have an app where you can press on a screen and a method gets executed, and where you can long press and another method gets executed. The problem is, when I long press on the screen the normal onClickListener also gets executed, which I don't want.
They both are simple onClickListeners, the normal one is using the MotionEvent ACTION_UP. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?
So I don't want to execute the ACTION_UP in the normal onTouchListener when the onLongClickListener executed.

Code:

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you, if you post some code (your Listeners).

Comment: updated the question tom include code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to onTouch

```
    int flag=0
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(flag==0){
              //do something 
            }else{
              flag=0;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
});
layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        flag=1
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`LongClick` and `Click` are in the same level, while `Touch` isn't (actually LongClick an Click are dispatched from onTouchEvent).

In your code, you always return `false` in `onTouch` method, so you don't comsume the event and it will be passed to the next level (LongClick, Click...), this is why when you long press the screen you have the both method called.

- **Suggestion1:**

Use `ClickListener` instead of `TouchListener`.

- **Suggestion2:**

Use [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to handle all events (touch, longclick...). This is an [example](http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener)

- **Suggestion3:**

Use a flag to perform the desired event.

```
private boolean longClick = false;


layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if (longClick) {
             longClick = false;
          }
        return false;
    }
});

layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        longClick = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

- **Suggestion4:**

Use a handler with runnable. [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11702558/4224337) and [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679788/4224337)

Answer (score 0):

If onclick does the same as you intended use onclick listner instead of ontouch that way you wont trigger onclick when you longclick.